# Will setState inside componentWillReceiveProps run before render?

Tags: reactjs

The react docs mention that calls to `setState` are enqueued, and do not happen immediately. Does react make any guarantees that `setState` enqueued inside `componentWillReceiveProps` will execute before the next component render? Are either of these scenarios more likely than the other?

1. props change > componentWillReceiveProps called > setState enqueued > setState runs > render (which includes new state)
2. props change > componentWillReceiveProps called > setState enqueued > render > setState runs > re-rendered

Or, are both of these scenarios equally likely? Meaning does React not make any guarantees when setState will run relative to component lifecycle methods?

Here is a ES2015 code excerpt of my example:

```
import React from 'react';

class Widget extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <a onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.triggerExternalPropsChange();
      }}>
        Click me to trigger new props
      </a>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Where `triggerExternalPropsChange` passes new props to the `Widget` component.

Comment: Both of these are likely. You should always setup up render to complete successfully regardless of whether state has completed getting set or not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only reason `componentWillReceiveProps` exists is to give the component an opportunity to `setState`. So yes, any state you set synchronously in it will be processed together with the new props. There won’t be two renders in this case, just one.

Comment: `this.setState({foo: 'bar'})` is asynchronous according to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate.

What should I do if  I need to change state based on previous state and new props? Using updater function does not work, render is called only once with old state and new props...

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean by "updater function"? Dan is saying here that you can synchronously setState inside componentWillReceiveProps, in which you can access next props, current props, and current state.

Comment: @Evan according to setState doc, updater is arrow function in: `this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step};
});`. For more details check https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10111

Comment: @Marcin Are you running into some specific problem? `this.setState(...)` will work as expected in `componentWillReceiveProps()`. There is nothing extra you need to do. Source: I work on React.

Comment: @DanAbramov my problem was a result of mistake in JS syntax. You can see more details in the link from my last comment. I apologize for generating noise here.

Comment: So in short - scenario 1 described in the question - is right (and only it) ?

Comment: Thx @Marcin. I had similar issue but inTS. I used **await** this.setState({}) 
 instead of simply this.setState({}) in componentWillReceiveProps and now everything works

Answer (score 1):

It's 1.

Calling setState() in componentWillReceiveProps() is an exception in the sense of executing state update before the component renders, so you will get both props changes and state changes applied in the same render.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, both are likely. React will try to render anytime it gets new props or state and because it does dom diffing, it tries to render as often as possible. You have options to control it though, using `shouldComponentUpdate` you can check and wait until both props and state have been updated before rendering.